# XBMC - watch streamed video in local network

Tags: video-streaming, xbmc

I have been searching for this problem for a while now.
I am trying to stream a video from my computer (with Ubuntu 12.04) and I want to watch that stream with my XBMC program. Right now I am using VLC to stream the video.
Is there a way to do this? 
If you need additional information tell me and I'll give it, I'm new to all this so sorry if this is a rookie question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any DLNA-compliant UPnP Media Server, like [PS3 Media Server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/about/).

I used it for years, now they support many platforms, including XBMC.

[]s